# Google Script - Increment the data range every time script is run using using Apps script on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a list from one cell that is consistently updated in google sheets.

I have the following code inside my function.

```
 var app = SpreadsheetApp;

var tS = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard");

var tempNum =  tS.getRange(18,11).getValue();

var ttS = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GraphData");

var ud = ttS.getRange('A1').setValue(tempNum);
```

How do I add the value stored in *tempNum* to a new row every time the script is executed?

I will then trigger the script once per day to set the new value into the row below and then create a graph from said values.

Thanks in advance, let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). There is no question in your post. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oops! Sorry, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append the value stored in `tempNum` to a new row at the end of the `GraphData` sheet every time the script is executed, use [Sheet.appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents), like this:

```
  ttS.appendRow([tempNum]);
```

See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).